# Revert to HTTP from HTTPS when there is no REQUEST_URI

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have a set of rewrite rules as follows which handle routing of requests over HTTP and HTTPS depending on the path:

```bash
# Force SSL for certain URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond $1 ^(admin|checkout|client-area) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Force Non-SSL for other URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Placeholder for requests without a URI here
RewriteCond $1 !^(admin|checkout|client-area) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However I have noticed that if a user navigates to `/checkout` for example, and then back to the home page (where there is no `REQUEST_URI`) the HTTPS protocol persists. I've tried adding the following:

```bash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
```

But to no avail. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In my experience, REQUEST_URI always exists. And since it includes the leading slash I don't think it can match `!^$`.

Comment: Hmm, there must be some way to match on a condition where there is nothing after the domain OR simply a trailing slash. :/

Comment: Should be `!^/$`, no? The URI *always* has a leading slash.

Comment: Nope - I've tried that too... no cigar. :(

Comment: Clear your browser's cache.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. I'm tempted to just serve the whole site over HTTPS, because well... that would make life easier! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I stumbled across a post here https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/6510/389 which got me headed in the right direction. I needed to add another condition block as follows after those above:

```
# Force Non-SSL for the home page (only)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^ACT= [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond $1 ^$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

That seems to do it! :)